# What goes into a file header?

Tags: file, header, filesystems, file-header

I keep wondering "what goes info a file header" and all I can find is "what goes into a C header file" which is not what I want, I want to know what goes into for example a tarball's or an ELF executable's header, anything generic or does it depend per file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Depends per file type**, they sit as a data specification known as **"file format specification"** and somewhat proprietary registered (example .exe).
Best example is **EXIF image headers**.
It heavily coincides data and data transfer specifications can be found throughout IETF rfc's.